# C# error while saving new record entity framwork

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I have table in sql as

```
 USE [testDB]
 GO

 /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[MemberPanel]    Script Date: 03/01/2013 19:21:01 ******/
 SET ANSI_NULLS ON
 GO

 SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
 GO

 CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MemberPanel](
[UserId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
[PanelId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Status] [int] NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_MemberPanel] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
 (
[UserId] ASC,
[PanelId] ASC
 )WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
 ) ON [PRIMARY]

 GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberPanel]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_MemberPanel_Member]      FOREIGN KEY([UserId])
 REFERENCES [dbo].[Member] ([UserId])
 GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberPanel] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_MemberPanel_Member]
 GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberPanel]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT      [FK_PracticePanel_PracticePanel] FOREIGN KEY([PanelId])
 REFERENCES [dbo].[Panel] ([PanelId])
 GO

 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MemberPanel] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PracticePanel_PracticePanel]
 GO
```

I use entity framwork and use c# code as

```
 public static bool AddMemberPanels(List<int> panelIDs, Guid userId, int status)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FairShareEntities fairShareEntities = new FairShareEntities())
            {
                foreach (var panelID in panelIDs)
                {
                    var panel = new MemberPanel() { UserId = userId, PanelId = panelID,      Status = status };
                    fairShareEntities.AddToMemberPanel(panel);
                    fairShareEntities.SaveChanges();
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

on save changes it through error

```
      {"Entities in 'TestEntities.MemberPanel' participate in the                'FK_MemberPanel_Member' relationship. 0 related 'Member' were found. 1 'Member' is expected."}
```

Please help me here I don't know why it does not allow me to add new record , I have also check all values i.e UserID and PanelId , yes they exist in there tables as PK.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is `TestEntities.MemberPanel`  in your code? And could you please provide code of `fairShareEntities.AddToMemberPanel(panel)` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolve this thanks to every one:

```
 public static bool AddMemberPanels(List<int> panelIDs, Guid memberId, int status)
    {
        try
        {
            using (FairShareEntities fairShareEntities = new FairShareEntities())
            {
                foreach (var panelId in panelIDs)
                {
                    //get the member and panels
                    Member theMember =
                        (from m in fairShareEntities.Member.Include("MemberPanel") where m.UserId == memberId select m).FirstOrDefault();

                    //see if this Member is already on this Panel
                    if (!(from mp in theMember.MemberPanel where mp.PanelId == panelId select mp).Any())
                    {

                        //get the panel
                        Panel thePanel = (from p in fairShareEntities.Panel where p.PanelId == panelId select p).FirstOrDefault();

                        //add the panel to this Member
                        MemberPanel addMemberPanel = new MemberPanel()
                        {
                            UserId = memberId,
                            Status = status,
                            Panel = thePanel,
                            PanelId = panelId
                        };
                        theMember.MemberPanel.Add(addMemberPanel);
                        fairShareEntities.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }

                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the exact problem, but in EF you should not generally set the foreign key ID. Instead, you should pull the User and Panel entities from the database and set the navigation properties of the new MemberPanel entity to them...

```
var newMemberPanel = ... // as you have already
newMemberPanel.Panel = existingPanel;
newMemberPanel.User = existingUser;
```

I think this might work better.

Also, you might be better off creating the new entity using the methods on the context, rather than creating it in isolation and then adding it to the context. I have found that this is sometimes a more stable way to do it. You should be able to do something like this...

```
 var newMemberPanel = ctx.MemberPanels.Add();
```

...and then carry on as I showed above.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

That's a foreign key error.  It's an SQL error not an entity framework error.

You need to add a "Member" object before adding a "MemberPanel".

Your database shema specify this:

```
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MemberPanel_Member] FOREIGN KEY([UserId]) 
    REFERENCES [dbo].[Member] ([UserId])
```

So the specified UserId need to be in table Member

then work with your entities not with ID

```
var myLovedUser = fairShareEntities.Members.Where(x=>x.UserId = userID);
var incrediblePanel =  fairShareEntities.Panels.Where(x=>x.PanelId = panelId);
var memberPanel = new MemberPanel() {User = myLovedUser, Panel=incrediblePanel, Status= status };
fairShareEntities.AddToMemberPanel(panel);
fairShareEntities.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Isn't that what he's doing with: UserId = userId when he creates the member panel?

Comment: The "userId" is a function parameter.  We have no idea how it has been obtain.  It need to exist in the database.

Comment: I do this var panel = new MemberPanel() { UserId = userId, PanelId = panelID, Status = status };
                        panel.Member = member; but bad luck same error , Please help me to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace frmSales
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        //create object for models
        tblSales modelSales = new tblSales();
        tblSalesLines modelSalesLine = new tblSalesLines();
        View_1 modelView = new View_1();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadCmbBox();
        }

        //Fill dropdown
        private void LoadCmbBox()
        {
            using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities ())
            {
                var name = from tblProduct in db.tblProduct
                           select tblProduct;

                comboBox1.DataSource = name.ToList();
                comboBox1.DisplayMember = "barcode";
            }
        }

        //txtCName accepts only alphabetical characters
        private void txtCName_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && !(e.KeyChar == 8) && !(e.KeyChar == 32))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("This textbox accepts only alphabetical characters", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        //txtPhone accepts only Numbers
        private void txtPhone_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9' || e.KeyChar == 8))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("This textbox accepts only Numbers", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        //txtDec accepts only alphabetical characters
        private void txtDec_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!char.IsLetter(e.KeyChar) && !(e.KeyChar == 8) && !(e.KeyChar == 32))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("This textbox accepts only alphabetical characters", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        //txtQtc accepts only Numbers
        private void txtQtc_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9' || e.KeyChar == 8))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("This textbox accepts only Numbers", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        //txtUPrice accepts only Numbers
        private void txtUPrice_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(e.KeyChar >= '0' && e.KeyChar <= '9' || e.KeyChar == 8))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                MessageBox.Show("This textbox accepts only Numbers", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }

        private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //AddButton();

            if (txtCName.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Customer Name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (txtAddress.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Address", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (txtPhone.Text == "")
            {enter code here
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Telephone Number", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (txtDec.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Description", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (txtQtc.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Quantity", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (txtUPrice.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Unit Price", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                AddButton();
                txtDec.Text = txtQtc.Text = txtUPrice.Text = txtTotal.Text = "";
            }
        }

        int rCount = 0;
        decimal amount = 0;
        private void AddButton()
        {
            if (txtDec.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Description", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (txtQtc.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Quantity", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else if (txtUPrice.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Unit Price", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

                rCount++;
                dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[0].Value = rCount;
                dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[1].Value = txtDec.Text;
                dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[2].Value = txtQtc.Text;
                dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[3].Value = txtUPrice.Text;
                dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1].Cells[4].Value = txtTotal.Text;

                amount = amount + Convert.ToDecimal(txtTotal.Text);
                txtAmount.Text = Convert.ToString(amount);
            }

        }

        private void txtUPrice_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtTotal.Text = "";
            if (txtUPrice.Text != "" && txtQtc.Text != "")
            {
                double Total = Convert.ToInt32(txtQtc.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtUPrice.Text);
                txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(Total);
            }

        }

        private void txtQtc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtTotal.Text = "";
            if (txtUPrice.Text != "" && txtQtc.Text != "")
            {
                double Total = Convert.ToInt32(txtQtc.Text) * Convert.ToDouble(txtUPrice.Text);
                txtTotal.Text = Convert.ToString(Total);
            }
        }
        int invoiceNum = 1910020001;
        int invoiceCount = 0001;
        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (cmbSalesType.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter Sales Type", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                invoiceCount++;

                modelSales.InvNo = invoiceNum + invoiceCount;
                modelSales.SalesDate = DateTime.Now;
                modelSales.Amount = Convert.ToInt32(txtAmount.Text);
                modelSales.CustomerName = txtCName.Text;
                modelSales.Address = txtAddress.Text;
                modelSales.Tel = Convert.ToInt32(txtPhone.Text);
                modelSales.SalesType = cmbSalesType.Text;

                using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
                {
                    db.tblSales.Add(modelSales);
                    db.SaveChanges();


                    var select = (from tblSales in db.tblSales
                                  select tblSales.SalesID).Max();

                    modelSalesLine.SalesID = Convert.ToInt32(select);

                    for (int rows = 0; rows < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; rows++)
                    {
                        int col = 1;

                        modelSalesLine.ProductName = dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[col++].Value.ToString();
                        modelSalesLine.Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[col++].Value.ToString());
                        modelSalesLine.UnitPrice = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[col++].Value.ToString());
                        modelSalesLine.Total = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[rows].Cells[col++].Value.ToString());


                        db.tblSalesLines.Add(modelSalesLine);
                        db.SaveChanges();

                        MessageBox.Show("data saved successfully", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }

                }
            }
        }

        private void btnViewInvoice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities())
            {
                DSsales ds = new DSsales();

                //Fil DT Sales
                var select = (from tblSales in db.tblSales
                              select tblSales.SalesID).Max();
                int maxId = Convert.ToInt32(select);

                var result = from tblSalesLines in db.tblSalesLines
                             where tblSalesLines.SalesID == maxId
                             select tblSalesLines;

                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    var sales = ds.DT_SalesLine.NewDT_SalesLineRow();

                    sales[0] = item.SalesLineID;
                    sales[1] = item.SalesID;
                    sales[2] = item.ProductName;
                    sales[3] = item.Quantity;
                    sales[4] = item.UnitPrice;
                    sales[5] = item.Total;

                    ds.DT_SalesLine.AddDT_SalesLineRow(sales);
                }

                //Fil DT SalesLine
                var result1 = from tblSales in db.tblSales
                              where tblSales.SalesID == maxId
                              select tblSales;

                foreach (var item in result1)
                {
                    var sales = ds.DT_Sales1.NewDT_Sales1Row();

                    sales[0] = item.SalesID;
                    sales[1] = item.InvNo;
                    sales[2] = item.SalesDate;
                    sales[3] = item.Amount;
                    sales[4] = item.CustomerName;
                    sales[5] = item.Address;
                    sales[5] = item.Tel;
                    sales[5] = item.SalesType;

                    ds.DT_Sales1.AddDT_Sales1Row(sales);
                }
                CRSalesReport rpt = new CRSalesReport();
                rpt.SetDataSource(ds);

                frmCRsales frmCRsales = new frmCRsales();
                frmCRsales.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;

                frmCRsales.ShowDialog();
                frmCRsales.Dispose();
            }
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.Equals(5) && e.RowIndex != -1)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Remove(dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]);
            }
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox1.Text = "-- Select Barcode --";
        }

        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (DBEntities db = new DBEntities ())
            {
                try
                {
                    string barcode = comboBox1.Text;
                    var result2 = db.tblProduct.Where(x => x.barcode == barcode).FirstOrDefault();
                    txtDec.Text = result2.productName;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {

                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```